# How to add scale in response of button for gtk+

Tags: visual-c++, gtk3

I am going to create a simple user interface that has a button which controls a value, and when user click on it, a vscale appear in new window or dialog or box and so on to set value with scale. 
is there any example of such program?
I am googled and find some examples but they set color and the dialog have functions for font selection and... .
Win 7_64 bit, gtk3.4.2, Visual c++
regards

Comment: You could just create `GtkDialog` add the scale to its content area, add some buttons and run it. Don't forget to retrieve the value of the scale before you destroy the dialog, otherwise it is lost for ever.

Comment: Do you have any example?

Comment: I'm more a python guy, so I can only provide you a example in Python :)

Comment: Thanks. I write a sample that works correctly but need to be edited, it will come soonly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code :

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

 void value_changed(GtkRange *range, gpointer win) {

 gdouble val = gtk_range_get_value(range);
 gchar *str = g_strdup_printf("%.f", val);    
 gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(win), str);

 g_free(str);
 }

void value(GtkRange *range, gpointer win)
 {

GtkWidget *halign;
GtkWidget *hbox;
GtkWidget *hscale;
GtkWidget *label;

GtkWidget *content_area, *label1;
GtkWidget * dia = gtk_dialog_new();
content_area = gtk_dialog_get_content_area (GTK_DIALOG (dia)); 


  hbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL,FALSE);

  hscale = gtk_scale_new_with_range(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL,0, 100, 1);
 gtk_scale_set_draw_value(GTK_SCALE(hscale), FALSE);
 gtk_widget_set_size_request(hscale, 150, -1);
 label = gtk_label_new("...");
 gtk_misc_set_alignment(GTK_MISC(label), 0.0, 1);

 gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), hscale, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
 gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), label, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

 halign = gtk_alignment_new(0, 0, 0, 0);


 gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(halign), hbox);
 gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(content_area), halign);



g_signal_connect(hscale, "value-changed",
  G_CALLBACK(value_changed), label);     


label1 = gtk_label_new ("YA ali");

gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (content_area), label1);
gtk_widget_show_all (dia);

  }


 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

 GtkWidget *window;
 GtkWidget *halign;
 GtkWidget *hbox;
 GtkWidget *hscale;
 GtkWidget *label;


 GtkWidget *table;
 GtkWidget *btn;

 gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

 window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
 gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
 gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 250);
 gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);
 gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GtkHScale");

 btn = gtk_button_new();
 table = gtk_table_new(10,10,TRUE);
gtk_table_set_row_spacings(GTK_TABLE(table), 10);
gtk_table_set_col_spacings(GTK_TABLE(table), 10);

 gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table),btn,2,4,4,6);
 gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), table);




 g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(btn), "clicked", 
  G_CALLBACK(value), G_OBJECT(window));

 g_signal_connect(window, "destroy",
   G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);


 gtk_widget_show_all(window);

gtk_main();

 return 0;
}
```